# Why doesn’t Carrie tell Saul that Brody can trick the lie detector?

Tags: homeland

In season 1 of Homeland,

Carrie *knows* that Brody can trick the lie detector, because of the last question (she has slept with him, he lies about it, but the lie detector doesn’t recognize it as lie).

She can’t tell it someone at this point, because she doesn’t want to disclose her relationship with Brody.

Later she discloses the relationship (at least to Saul). At this point, all the others (including Saul) still don’t believe that Brody is a terrorist.

Why doesn’t Carrie tell them (or only Saul) at this point about Brody’s tricking of the lie detector? Of course it wouldn’t prove that he is a terrorist, but it could be an important evidence.

Answer (score 4):

Brody admits to Carrie that he did indeed convert to Islam but he insists that he is not a terrorist (S1E7). Soon after that, Carrie learns that Tom Walker is alive and hence all suspicions are on him from that moment onward. Carrie is more or less convinced that she was wrong about Brody. Also, after the episode at the bunker where nothing happens to the Vice president she believes that Brody cannot be a terrorist (even though she correctly deduces that the Sniper fire was just a cover to get Brody into the bunker).

I am not sure of the episode where Carrie reveals her relationship to Saul, but if it is in the later episodes of S1, well... by then Carrie believes that Brody is not a threat.

If you are talking about later seasons then I guess that the polygraph test must have lost its significance or maybe the electroshock therapy at the end makes her forget.

Answer (score -1):

Because this would involve hampering her own professional life (relation in professional life not permitted in CIA)

Comment: -1: The question asks why didn't she reveal this _even after_ admitting her relationship. She clearly wasn't hampering her professional life, since she had just _disclosed_ the relationship to Saul.

Comment: No she revealed this to saul personally thus keeping things light. But if she revealed her sexual secret, Saul would take this seriously and report it to higher authority (because a man who can bypass lie detector is a wonder as well as a suspect). If the higher authorities came to know about this, this would jeopardise her career, the reason behind which i posted earlier.